# C++ unable check ifstream/ofstream.is_open() inside a function

Tags: c++, scope, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I have written a code in C++ which reads from a text file or creates new one with with `ifstream`/`ofstream`. I wanted to add a check with **`.is_open`** member function of **`fstream`** to see if the files were successfully opened. It works correctly inside main loop. Then I tried to create a function outside the loop for this purpose, and call it inside `main`, and I got following error:

> `std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)` is private.

Is it possible to make the check outside of main loop? How? What am I doing wrong?

I would appreciate if you can help. You can find the code below.

P.S. I am newbie in C++, so please don't overcriticize unprofessional programming approaches if you see any. Though any recommendations for improvement are more than welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void check_opened(ifstream toget, ofstream togive){
    if(toget.is_open()){
        cout<<"able to open file(toread.txt)"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"failure"<<endl;
    }
    if(togive.is_open()){
        cout<<"able to create/open a file(newone.txt)"<<endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"failure"<<endl;
    }
}
int main () {
    ifstream toget;
    ofstream togive;
    toget.open("toread.txt");
    togive.open("newone.txt");
    check_opened(toget,togive);
    toget.close();
    togive.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error happens regardless of whether you have the `is_open` call or not. Part of making a [mcve] is challenging your assumptions.

Comment: You are passing `toget` and `togive` by value to the `check_opened` function. And it looks like it's not allowed to copy `ifstream`s nor `ofstream`s. Try passing them as references or pointers.

Comment: @gurka , Thanks a lot, I used it as reference and it worked.

Comment: But I don't understand why my version was not allowed. I guess I need to read a little about passing function arguments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `check_opened` does not take a reference to a stream, it takes a copy of one.  Thus when you call check_opened your main function implicitly invokes the copy constructor of `ifstream` and `ofstream`, which are private, which causes the error.  Changing the signature of check_opened to `void check_opened(ifstream&, ofstream&)` will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks you for explanation